# How to remove values from a list that are less than a target value from the previous number

Tags: python, list

Given a sorted list of increasing numbers, I'm trying to create a new list that only keeps values that are at least 3 greater than the previous number.  I have tried some conditional statements, but fail to get the correct format. For example, from

```
a = [3,4,8,12,14,16]
```

we would obtain

```
new_a = [3,8,12,16]
```

Only 14 would drop out because it is less than 3 away from 12, but keep 16 because it is greater than 3 from 12. Also 4 would drop out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the list is definitely sorted, you could just store the previous value as a temporary variable and check against it until it is 3 larger.

Comment: can you please show the code that you have tried?

Comment: What should the result be for `[2,4,6,8,10,12]`?

Comment: This would give [2, 6, 10]

Comment: I don't know if my solution is the best one for the case but it works with both of your lists

Comment: why not `[4,8,12,16]` and `[4,8,12]`? What is the rule: you want to get the longest possible list or just greedily kick out the next one that's too close?

Comment: @V22: Why wouldn't the solution to `[2,4,6,8,10,12]` be `[4,8,12]`? Or `[2,6,12]`? Or `[2,8,12]`? Or...

Comment: Because this list is created from indexes that meet a specific value.  Once this list is created, it looks for the first occurrence that satisfies it then can not happen until (or at least) 3 indexes later. So 2 would be the first index that satisfies it, then has to wait at least 3 until the next index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```
new_a = a[:1]
for i in a[1:]:
    if i >= new_a[-1] + 3:
        new_a.append(i)
```

Comment: @sparkandshine: that would have to be `new_a = [a[0]]` because it has to be a list with the first element of a. Not sure if this is more straightforward, but both is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3,4,8,12,14,16]
b = a[:1]
last_num = b[0]
for num in a:
    if last_num is not None and last_num + 3 <= num:
        b.append(num)
        last_num = num

print(b)
```

Comment: `if last_num is not None` is needed because this currently won't handle a 0.

Comment: I'm curious. In the first part of your if statement, you use `last_num` to see if you are looking at the first item in list `a`, but in the second part you use `len(b)`. Why the change?

Comment: To add the first item in the `b` list..I fixed it but yet I think that Tim Hoffmann solution is much better

Answer (score 0):

Possibly overkill, but if you end up doing this computation a lot (as well as adding new numbers to the list) you can try subclassing `list`.

```
class Newlist(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Newlist, self).__init__(*args)
        if len(self) > 0:
            i = 1
            while i<len(self):
                if self.__getitem__(i) < 3+self.__getitem__(i-1):
                    self.remove(self.__getitem__(i))
                i += 1

    def append(self, item):
        if len(self) == 0:
            super(Newlist, self).append(item)
        elif item >= self.__getitem__(-1) + 3:
            super(Newlist, self).append(item)
        else: return
```

Thus you can initialize a list with

```
a = Newlist([3, 4, 8, 12, 14, 16])
```

Which will automatically be shortened to `[3, 8, 12, 16]`

Also `append` is overriden to only allow new values that follow your rule. Example: `a.append(20)` will add `20` to the end of `a`, but `a.append(17)` will do nothing.